# R Vlookup Two Criteria and Fill in the Value

Tags: r, dataframe, vlookup

Actual dataframe consist of more than a million rows.

Say for example a dataframe is:

```
UniqueID  Code  Value  OtherData      
1         A     5      Z01 
1         B     6      Z02
1         C     7      Z03
2         A     10     Z11
2         B     11     Z24
2         C     12     Z23 
3         A     10     Z21
```

I want to obtain ratio of A/B. For example, for UniqueID 1, its ratio of A/B = 5/6.

Thus, I transform the original dataframe to:

```
UniqueID  A_Value  B_Value  Ratio_A/B    
1         5       
2         10
3         10
```

Question is, how do I lookup the original dataframe by its UniqueID and then fill in its B value? If there is no B value, then just return 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove the columns which are not necessary, select only rows where `Code` has value `"A"` or `"B"`, get the data in wide format and create a new column with the value of `A/B`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(-OtherData) %>%
  filter(Code %in% c("A", "B")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Code, values_from = Value, values_fill = list(Value = 0)) %>%
  #OR if you want to have NA values instead of 0 use
  #pivot_wider(names_from = Code, values_from = Value) %>%
  mutate(Ratio_A_B = A/B)

#  UniqueID     A     B Ratio_A_B
#     <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1        1     5     6     0.833
#2        2    10    11     0.909
#3        3    10     0      Inf
```